Common root among の～ verbs?
This is probably a bit of a stretch but I've noticed that a lot of verbs starting with の have some sense of something going (or being) upward or outward. Between Jisho and Wiktionary I found the following:
upward movement:

載{の}る - to place on
乗{の}る - to get on
登{のぼ}る・昇{のぼ}る・上{のぼ}る - to go up

speaking:

惚気{のろけ}る - to go on about (something one loves)
宣{の}る - to declare
述{の}べる - to express

extending:

伸{の}びる・延{の}びる - to stretch; to postpone

being excluded:

除{のぞ}く - to exclude
残{のこ}る - to be left
逃{のが}れる - to escape

From Wiktionary I gather that some of these (のびる, のべる, and maybe のぼる?) derive from an older のぶ but beyond that I haven't been able to find much about the origins of these words. Is there any sort of really old root that some or all of these might be related to or is this just coincidence?

I doubt that most of them (outside of one group containing のびる, のべる, and maybe のぼる, and another group containing various のる verbs) are related to each other. のがれ​る is possibly related to にげ​る. のろける is strongly excluded from being related to all others, since Old Japanese had no native words starting with r, so noroke- cannot be compound of no- + roke-.
